# Fetching greek column names from sql server with php

Tags: php, html, sql-server, encoding

I have a greek sql server 2008 database and i get the data with php to a website.The database data are `nvarchar`.In the connection to the server i have the character-set to `utf-8` and in the html files `charset="utf-8"`.

When i fetch data from the database everything is fine, but when i try to fetch column names with `sqlsrv_field_metadata()` , it shows up in the browser with questionmarks.
If i get the column names from the view `information_schema.columns` they show up fine.

What should i do?

Is there a way to check if the column names are `nvarchar`?

**UPDATE:**It turns out it is a sql server driver for php bug and it the issue has been added on Codeplex http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/workitem/22417

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting with

```
sqlsrv_connect ($serverName, array('CharacterSet' => 'windows-1253'));
```

Comment: I want to use the pChart library and if i use windows-1253 the chart can't show the characters,it supports utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the mssql modules instead of the old sqlsrv library.

To call you would use:

```
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 


$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

//execute a stored procedure:
$query = "exec eCommerce.dbo.products_GET_Product_php @productId = $pid, @countryCode = " . $_SESSION['cc'] . ", @sid = ". $_SESSION['sid'];

$result = mssql_query($query);

while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
 $pagetitle = $row["product_name"];
}
```